# Explained shell statement

Tags: shell, sed, io, cat

The following statement will remove line numbers in a txt file:

```
cat withLineNumbers.txt | sed 's/^.......//' >> withoutLineNumbers.txt
```

The input file is created with the following statement (this one i understand):

```
nl -ba input.txt >> withLineNumbers.txt
```

I know the functionality of cat and i know the output is written to the 'withoutLineNumbers.txt' file. But the part of `'| sed 's/^.......//''` is not really clear to me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's not nice, to abuse cats...

Comment: Please explain what you mean explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sed regular expression simply removes the first 7 characters from each line. The regular expression `^.......` says "Any 7 characters at the beginning of the line." The sed argument `s/^.......//` substitutes the above regular expression with an empty string.

Refer to the `sed(1)` man page for more information.

Comment: The pipe redirects all output from cat into sed. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Comment: | redirects output of one process to the input of another

Answer (score 0):

sed is doing a search and replace. The 's' means search, the next character ('/') is the seperator, the search expression is '^.......', and the replace expression is an empty string (i.e. everything between the last two slashes).

The search is a regular expression. The '^' means match start of line. Each '.' means match any character. So the search expression matches the first 7 characters of each line. This is then replaced with an empty string. So what sed is doing is removing the first 7 characters of each line.

A more simple way to achieve the same think could be:

```
cut -b8- withLineNumbers.txt > withoutLineNumbers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

that sed statement says the delete the first 7 characters. a dot "." means any character. There is an even easier way to do this

```
 awk  '{print $2}' withLineNumbers.txt
```

you just have to print out the 2nd column using awk. No need to use regex

if your data has spaces,

```
awk  '{$1="";print substr($0,2)}' withLineNumbers.txt
```

Comment: What if his data set has spaces in it?